# Why would my entity not return with updated values?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Customer entity defined in EF Code First with an AccountNumber property.  I can get and update a single Customer with their AccountNumber without issue.  But when I get all Customers the AccountNumber is old for sometime and then eventually updates after a change.  The database always returns the correct AccountNumber value.

I have profiled SQLServer and found that the call to get all Customers does make it to the database and it returns the latest value but the response from the DbContext gives an old AccountNumber.  So it seems like EFCF is caching my data.

Please help.

UPDATE: Code examples -

```
        public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return this.acmeDbContext.Customer
            .Include(x => x.IpAddressRange)
            ;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(Guid id)
    {
        var Customer = this.acmeDbContext.Customer
            .Include(x => x.Contacts)
            .Include(x => x.IpAddressRange)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == id);
        return Customer;
    }
    public void SaveCustomer(Customer Customer)
    {
        this.acmeDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code that is saving/updating the AccountNumber as well as code where you are reading that value but it's not current.

Comment: Yes EF caches data. You have to overwrite the cache explicitly, google for RefreshMode.StoreWins. Since there is no code it's hard to tell where to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Reload method to reload each customer:

```
        if (noCache)
            customers.ToList().ForEach(x => acmeDbContext.Entry(x).Reload());
```